# ExpressJS octet-stream sha checksum missmatch with openssl-dgt/sha256sum

Tags: express, hash, octet-stream

I have the following request handler:

```js
//app.ts:
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.raw());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    apr.use(routeHandler);

// routeHandler.ts:
(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const {digest} = req.query;
    freshDigest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(req.body).digest('hex');
    if(digest !== freshDigest) throw ValidationError('digest mismatch');
}
```

Then I use the following curl command to post an `application/octet-stream` onto the route

```bash
curl 
  -H'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
  -XPOST \
  -v \
  "localhost:port/v2/path/to/route/?digest=sha256:$(sha256sum /path/to.file.html|cut -d' ' -f1)" \
  -d@/path/to.file.html.html \
  -H'Authorization: Bearer REDACTED'
```

The file may be any type, tarball, text, etc, just posting some bytes onto the API.

The digest provided by sha256sum (and openssl dgst -sha256) differ from node's crypto digest.

Is there anything that I misuse?

Thank you

Comment: Well, the issue was that cURL should send the data as binary, i.e. `--data-binary @/path/to/file`
Then the checksums would match.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was that cURL should send the data as binary, i.e. `--data-binary @/path/to/file` Then the checksums would match.